# Get all Business Recommended Fields

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-4

Is there an easy way to check all Business Recommended Fields on a form?

We would like to do some small changes to a field in the entity when someone change one of the Business Recommended field ON the form (so not modified by a system process).

Comment: What is a "Business Recommended Field"? (*edit* oh nm. must be a CRM thing)

Comment: In CRM, it's a field with the constraint "Business Recommended" applied, it should be represented by a little blue "+" sign on the side of the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as you have tagged your question as javascript I will assume you want these changes to be performed on the form level.

To tell when someone has a changed a Business Recommended field, you will have to add an On Change event, so the question then becomes how do you add these On Change handlers.

1. Manually add handlers to the Business Recommended Fields - the most supported and easiest way to do it (unless you have hundreds of fields, in which case it might take a long time).
2. Browse the DOM using javascript looking for '+' and add them that way - more difficult and not supported.
3. Query the Crm Metadata service, then browse the DOM and add them - again more difficult and not supported.

I would go with 1.